# handle screen off, onStop

Tags: android

I had an app which had a target as 8. Whenever the screen was turned off the onPause was called while the onStop wasn't. Now when I changed the targetsdk to 18 the onStop is now getting called whenever the screen is turned off.
The thing is I want some actions to continue even when the screen is turned off, however when the home button is pressed or because of some reason the screen changes i.e onStop is called the behavior should stay as before. I don't want to put anything in onDestroy as there is a chance that it will be never called.

The action involves releasing some resources. If I don't release it, there might be problems. I know as of Honeycomb API level 13, the onStop is the last guaranteed call.

In short app behavior:
if screen on : onStop behaves as before i.e. operation stops
if screen is off : the operation continues and resources are released elsewhere

I know we can find whether screen is on or off using PowerManager.
Any ideas as to what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

When the screen goes off, you should in OnStop method start a background service to do what job you want in the background.